# Using WHERE IN with a COLLECT where the collect is creating a map

Tags: neo4j, cypher, collect

I have a neo4j graph which defines words relationships.  Each word node has an [r:IS_RELATED_TO] relationship with any other words of similar nature.  There is a similarity value on that relationship.

I need to search on a list of words being passed in.  The following query has a long way to go, but I am stuck on how to use the WHERE clause.

```
WITH 
['landscape', 'photography', 'exposure'] as searchTermWords

//get all the words similar to those in the search term
match 
(w1:WordGraph_Word)-[r:IS_RELATED_TO]-(w2:WordGraph_Word)
where w1.word in searchTermWords
WITH COLLECT({
word1:w1,
word2:w2,
similarity:r.similarityValue
}) as similarWords



//get all question collections with those similar words
match 
(qc:QuestionCollection)-[:HAS_WORD]->(w:WordGraph_Word)
where w in similarWords.word1

return *
```

When I execute this I get the following error:

```
Type mismatch: expected Any, Map, Node or Relationship 
but was List<Map> (line 19, column 12 (offset: 437))
"where w in similarWords.word1"
```

I also tried with "where w in similarWords.['word1']" and that also fails.

Any ideas would be most welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well, `similarWords` is collection, not a map, so the keys are integers and every element is a map you create in the `collect()`.

In order to make it a bit easier, I suggest a slight change in the collect :

```
WITH 
['landscape', 'photography', 'exposure'] as searchTermWords

//get all the words similar to those in the search term
MATCH
(w1:WordGraph_Word)-[r:IS_RELATED_TO]-(w2:WordGraph_Word)
where w1.word in searchTermWords
WITH w1, collect({word: w2, similarity: r.similarityValue}) AS similarWords
MATCH (w1)<-[:HAS_WORD]-(qc:QuestionCollection)
RETURN w1, similarWords, collect(qc) AS questions
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's really great.  With 500k "word" records the first execution is slow (38 seconds).  I guess it caches because the second execution is around 11ms.  I will have a play further :)